# Android Studio Arctic Fox keep showing white pop-up

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1.

I don't know what exactly the reason but there is a white pop-up show while coding:

[image]

How to turn it off?

Edited: I found that this bug occurs when I go to references functions by `Command + mouse click` on the function

Comment: It's may be bug. Try InvaildCache / Restart if not solve then please update android studio.

Comment: @UmeshYadav I always have to close Android Studio to ignore this error

Answer (score 3):

This is an open [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/196406762) in Android Studio Arctic Fox (as of late Aug 2021). Feel free to star the issue and maybe someone in the AS team might notice :-)

Comment: I see. Thank fyi

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to this problem

System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy (tab) -> Accessibility

Uncheck all the apps in the "Allow the apps below to control your computer" section.

restart the Android Studio , done.